# Green's Function ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following equation using Green's functions:

$u''-k^2u=f$  with boundary conditions $u(0)-u'(0)=a$ and $u(1)=b$

For this problem, I was going to find the green's function with homogeneous BC's (set both BC's equal to zero), and then I was going to add the solution to the homogeneous equation Lu = 0 (with the BC's given above) to the green's function solution.  However, when working out the green's function, I end up with constant that can't be solved.  Any help?

Comment: You should post your work so that we can see what, if anything, is wrong. It could be that you made a very simple mistake or something much more complicated and it is difficult for us to tell you what went wrong without seeing your work.

Comment: I would if my work didn't comprise 2+ pages :).  Basically, what I did was let Lu = delta(x-t).  Then, I solved out everything in the regions x<t and x>t; I get solutions of the form $g(x)=ae^(kx)+be^(-kx)$.  After doing so, I apply the BC's to both sides, eliminating 2 of the four constants.  Then, I assert continuity at x = t and ensure that the discontinuous derivative jump = 1.  I have 2 equations and 2 unknowns, but I can't solve for the constants =/ (it's super messy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I explained the process [for a similar example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/584858/). Here is a rehash:

1. Solve the characteristic equation $\lambda^2-k^2=0$
2. Write down the general solution of homogeneous equation: $y=  A\cosh k x+B\sinh kx $.
3. Find a solution $u$ such that $u(a)=0$ and $u'(a)=1$, where $a\in(0,1)$ is the pole of Green's function. Since the  equation is autonomous, solutions can be shifted in time:   $$u(x)=k^{-1} \sinh k(x-a) $$
4. By virtue of 3, the function $u(x)H(x-a)$,  where $H$ is the Heaviside function, produces $\delta_a$ when plugged into your equation.
5. Find a solution of homogeneous equation $y$ such that $y(x)+u(x)H (x-a)$ satisfies the homogeneous boundary condition. This amounts to asking $y(0)=y'(0)$ and $y(1)=-k^{-1} \sinh k(1-a)$. Hence, $$y(x)=-k^{-1} \sinh k(1-a)\cdot \frac{ k \cosh kx + \sinh  kx}{k \cosh k  + \sinh  k }$$
6. You have Green's function: $$g(x,a) = y(x)+u(x)H (x-a) $$